# When AWS ECS Container service changed state?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, amazon-ecs

I use CodeBuild to deploy containers to AWS ECS cluster.
Inside CodeBuild I've "aws ecs register-task-definition" and "aws ecs update-service" to register task definition and update the service with new task def. I have SNS subscription for changing ECS cluster state and I receive these notification for states in this order:

1. “PENDING to RUNNING”
2. “RUNNING to RUNNING"
3. “RUNNING to STOPPED"
4. “STOPPED to STOPPED”

Regarding [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs_cwe_events.html) I understand that the states  PENDING to RUNNING and RUNNING to STOPPED meaning that ECS Agent receives new tasks to start.

My question is what are other state means?

Answer (score 1):

There are two status for an ECS task. `lastStatus` means the current task status. `desiredStatus` means the targeted status.

During a task start and stop, there will be 4 events omitted:

1. (lastStatus: PENDING)-> (desiredStatus: RUNNING): The task is scheduled to run
2. (lastStatus: RUNNING)-> (desiredStatus: RUNNING): The task is started. There will be more data in the events such as network info, which is only available after task started.
3. (lastStatus: RUNNING)-> (desiredStatus: STOPPED): The task is scheduled to stop
4. (lastStatus: STOPPED)-> (desiredStatus: STOPPED): The task is stopped